react-native-google-mobile-ads not working in expo app
on running expo using web
it is giving error
Web Bundling failed 3315ms (D:\code\redirectToWhatsapp\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js)
error: node_modules\react-native-google-mobile-ads\lib\module\ads\GoogleMobileAdsBannerViewNativeComponent.js: D:\code\redirectToWhatsapp\node_modules\react-native-google-mobile-ads\lib\module\ads\GoogleMobileAdsBannerViewNativeComponent.js: Could not find component config for native component
I tried almost every thing
i need help for running admob ads on my react native expo app
thanks
